# Windows sublinux - get windows path where linux was called

Tags: linux, debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux

is it possible to get the directory path from Windows where for example "debian" was executed?

For example I open my projects with Visual Code and execute the NodsJs/npm projects from Windows WSL Debian. So it would be nice if "debian" is called from inside the Visual Code console that my linux subsystem auomatically joins the Windows directory from where I am coming. 
Yes I am already using symlinks but then I have to create a symlink for each project. An automatically solution would be much more comfortable.

I googled and haven't found something regarding this. Would be great if someone can tell me if this is possible or not.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. When I run WSL it autmatically sets the current working directory to the same directory I was in the windows shell. Is that not the case for you?

Comment: When i call debian inside my vs code powershell to switch to the wsl subsystem i am redirected to the home directory of the current debian user. The original path is something like /mnt/c/Users/.../Desktop for example inside debian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not sure what you meant but apparently there's a `debian.exe` that lands in the users home dir.

You can just use the `wsl.exe` to get the behavior that you described.

i.e. `wsl.exe -d "Debian"`

Which looks like this on the shell

```
PS C:\Users\PeterT> cd C:\DEV
PS C:\DEV> wsl.exe -d "Debian"
petert@debian:/mnt/c/DEV$
```

Comment: Yes that is the behaviour when you use wsl.exe for me. Did you try it?

Comment: Nice works :)  I just get -d: invalid option, when I only use wsl.exe it works. Maybe because I do not have the latest windows update.

Comment: @Schlumpf you can use `wslconfig.exe /l` to see what the name is on your PC, it just was "Debian" for me

Comment: On my system its Debian too which is associated with default. But -d is no valid argument for wsl.exe on my system. Maybe the argument was added in a newer Windows update. I am at version 1709. But well as long as I only use debian it's working with wsl.exe :)